# How can I get the last value entered from a set of selected cells in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have to get the last value entered in a set of selected cells in Excel. For Eg: In an Excel sheet in Column A I will enter the names of the students. In Column B, C, D, & E I will enter the Grades (say A,B,C & D)awarded to the student in each event. In the last Column F, I want to return the Grade which has got for his last event. Say there are 4 events. Student-1 has participated in all the 4 events and I will enter the Grades against each event and in the last column I want to display the Grade achieved by the Student-1 in the last event. Student-2 only participated in 2 events, so I will the Grades against those events. In the last column I want to display the Grade achieved by the Student in his last event out of the 2 which he participated.

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Unfortunately Excel don't keep track of last changed cell, you can't learn it without use of macros.

Comment: How do you type your question as one big paragraph? Try reading it yourself - it is too hard to read

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Common mistake some members make is formatting. Many people will not read a huge bock of difficult to read text. Taking a minute to [edit] your question to make it easier to read will increase your chances of getting the help you seek.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, in  **F2** enter:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(B2:E2<>""),B2:E2)
```

and copy down:

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

Here are some examples with sparsely filled input data:

[image]

also similar result from the Excel web app:

[image]

Comment: @fixer1234  On my system *(Win7 Excel 2007)* it only fails if **all** the cells from **B2** through **E2** are blank.

Comment: Interesting.  In LO Calc, it produces an error if there's an empty cell in the middle.

Comment: @fixer1234  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Looks like another subtle difference between Excel and LO Calc.  I upvoted since the question specifies Excel and this works in Excel.